Defining convex sums locally on the sphere?
$S^1$ and the torus $T^2$ are spaces in which convex combinations don't make sense globally but do locally. Despite their standard representations in $\mathbf{R}^2$ and $\mathbf{R}^3$ respectively not being convex themselves, given two close enough points of $S^1$ (more specifically, non-antipodal points) we can calculate their weighted average along the shortest path betweem them. Since $T^2\cong S^1\times S^1$, it's easy to see how $T^2$ also allows for some local definition of convex combination.
More formally, a space $X$ could be called locally convexable if $X$ possesed an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that each $U_i$ is equipped with a formal convex combination inner operation such that for any $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in[0,1]:\sum_j\lambda_j=1$ and for any $P_1,\ldots,P_n\in U_i$ we have

$1\cdot P_1+0\cdot P_2=P_1$ and $P_1=\lambda_1P_1+(1-\lambda_1)P_1$

$\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_{\sigma(j)}P_{\sigma(j)}$ for any $\sigma\in\Sigma_n$, i.e. the convex combination allows to commute the summands;

if $\lambda\in[0,1]$ and $P\in U_i$, then $$\lambda\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j\right)+(1-\lambda)P=\sum_{j=1}^n(\lambda\lambda_j)P_j+(1-\lambda)P;$$

for any $n\geq 2$, the map $c:\mathcal{T}^{n-1}\times U_i^n\to U_i$ given by
$$c(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n;P_1,\ldots,P_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\mu_jP_j,$$
where $\mathcal{T}^{n-1}=\{(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)\in[0,1]^n:\mu_1+\ldots+\mu_n=1\}$, is continuous;

and very importantly, the convex combination does not depend on the open set you're in, that is, if $P_1,\ldots,P_n\in U_{i'}$ then their convex combinations coincide in both $U_i$ and $U_{i'}$ (provided their coefficients coincide, of course).


Is the $2$-sphere locally convexable?
If we remove the condition about continuity, it would. Essentially, $S^2$ would inherit convex combinations from the space $\mathbf{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$ (to which it is homeomorphic) where $\infty$ acts as an absorbant (any convex combination where $\infty$ appears with a strictly positive coefficient is equal to $\infty$; otherwise convex combinations work as usual). This definition does not yield the wished continuity as you can easily check that $\infty$ is a problem.
If we remove the condition about the independence on the choice of $U_i$, it's trivially true as $S^2$ is locally homeomorphic to an open disc in $\mathbf{R}^2$.
If we remove the condition that the linear combinations behave well algebraically speaking, the naive approach of defining
$$\overline\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j:= \frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j}{\|\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jP_j\|}$$
for close enough $P_i$ (note that I used an overline over the first $\sum$ to stress that I'm talking about a formal sum) it's a quick check to see that it doesn't respect the distributivity axiom (the second one).
I thus suspect that $S^2$ might not be convexable. Can you (dis)prove this?
Note on injectivity: The axioms imply that if $P,Q\in U_i$ are distinct, then the map $c(\cdot; P,Q)$ is injective. Indeed suppose $\lambda P+(1-\lambda)Q=\mu P + (1-\mu)Q$ with $\lambda>\mu$. Then
$$\lambda P+(1-\lambda)Q=\frac\mu\lambda (\lambda P+(1-\lambda)Q)+(1-\frac\mu\lambda)Q$$
$$=\frac{\mu^2}\lambda P + (1-\frac{\mu^2}\lambda)Q$$
$$=\ldots =\mu\left(\frac\mu\lambda\right)^{2^n}P+[1-\mu\left(\frac\mu\lambda\right)^{2^n}]Q\to Q$$
But now observing $1-\mu>1-\lambda$ we can make the same expression tend to $P$. So $P=Q$ contradiction.

Do you want to assume injectivity of $c(\cdot, P_1,P_2,P_3)$ for nondegenerate triples?

Actually that's something I was pondering. In my attempts, the concept has proved to be key. I'll start by assuming it I guess.

With this extra assumption I can probably prove (I did not check the details) that a locally convexible surface admits a flat affine connection, which would imply (in the compact case) that it has to be $T^2$ or $K^2$. The same should hold in higher dimensions s well (locally "injectively" convexible is equivalent to existence of a flat affine connection).

Well, you know, how would define nondegenerate?

Injectivity seems to follow from the axioms. At least with 2 points. Check the updates to the post.

A triple is nondegenerate if none of the three points belongs to the convex hull of the other two.

It seems that your conditions imply that the manifold is affine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_manifold). So $\mathbb{S}^2$ does not have your property, but $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^1$ does (since it is a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by the action generated by $v\mapsto 2\cdot v$).

@AntonPetrunin: How would you get started without assuming injectivity?

@AntonPetrunin just wouldn'it be a quotient of $\mathbf{R}^3\setminus {0}$?

@MoisheKohan Probably injectivity for 3 and more nondegenerate sets of points can be deduced from the axioms in the same way that I've done it for 2 points.

Sure, it should be $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}$.
